# Remove Duplicates from ArrayList using key fields and sort by key fields and timestamp

Tags: java

I have a Arraylist where I am story a value object having below fields.

```
CaseId, StartDt, EndDt, Subject, Sub Subject, Status, Case Status , CrtTs
```

Out of above fields below can be used to identify a unique record or can say key fields

```
   StartDt, EndDt, Subject, Sub Subject, Status, Case Status
```

There is a possibility that we can have same similar records but there Timestamp help us identify which is the latest one.

Two lists have to create one where, A-SubFinal) we want to keep Latest date Key field combination in the list rest all duplicate and old date to be deleted as below.

B-Final) List have last Record of latest timestamp + key fields

please guide, how to achieve it. Below image can clarify more what I am asking.
Note: I have shown kind of sorted by TimeStamp.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this is down voted, any reason?

Answer (score 0):

1- Make a wrapper for your object (in this case a row in your table) and override its equals method to only consider your key fields

```
public class YourExtendedObject extends YourObject {

    private YourObject originalObject;

    public YourExtendedObject(YourObject yourObject) {
        this.originalObject = yourObject;
    }

    @Override
    // your equals override here to only consider the fields you want when considering duplicates
}
```

2- create some kind of Set of all the row objects, each wrapped in YourExtendedObject

3- if you want unique values here you should be done if I've understood correctly; if these unique values then need to be ordered based on timestamp, you can use a TreeSet with your own Comparator